# Best way to store a 3D Vector in MySql to grab entries within a distance?

Tags: mysql, vector, 3d

I am storing entries inside of a database and I would like to store a 3D vector in a field and then later select all rows within X distance of a 3D Vector given. I am thinking storing X,Y, and Z in its own fields and then doing basic greater then and less then signs, but is there a better way I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do the math every time if the start point is totally random. If you have a large dataset you could optimize by having a pre analysis for clusters of points which fall inside some minimum distance. Then you could avoid computations on all the points in a cluster.

I think that if you store your values in polar co-ordinates then there might be an optimization on the distance computation which reduces the number of computations.

Comment: I won't be doing the math regularly and it won't be a big dataset so I don't think I need to take measures in what you are suggesting, but thanks for the answer.